# 2 inches pvc pipe shower too short

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I had to cut my 2 inch pvc pipe to remove my old drain. I plan to tile my shower floor. How can I extend my pvc pipe (around 2 inches)? Can I connect a flange of 2.95 inches on the 2 inches pvc pipe?

All the help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You can't. You need to cut more like 4" to get one or two couplings and a pipe short in there. Or be a magician with a slip coupling. And you need access from below. Of which a picture'd be nice.

Comment: Got pics to show?